# Lubuntu overheating problem with ATI Radeon card 3650

Tags: graphics, lubuntu, overheating, amd-graphics, gpu

I am using Toshiba  A-300 series Laptop which is 8 years old..It has a dedicated graphics card ATI Radeon 3650 and an basic Intel graphics card as integrated one.. I have 2 OS dual boot(Windows 7 and Lubuntu 16.04.1)..With win7 i find no overheat problem ,when using simple application...But with lubuntu, i find my laptop start overheating even if i don't open any application....

I have seen many forum question regarding overheating issues, but confused with which one of them suits my solution....

Forums:

[ATI radeon mobility 3650 overheats and shuts down computer in Xubuntu and not Windows. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148073/ati-radeon-mobility-3650-overheats-and-shuts-down-computer-in-xubuntu-and-not-wi?rq=1)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2251930

[Laptop Overheats Running Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491793/laptop-overheats-running-ubuntu-14-04)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1936049

Please guide me..

Regards,
Vinoth R

Comment: Please could you post some links to these other posts.

Comment: I have added the links to your post so you can remove them in the comments.